# why isnt mongo returning object in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm searching for documents that contain a particular _id in the contacts array in the document. So here's the structure:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("505c2daea9d397f2260001cd"),
 "contacts": [
     {
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("50422b53743d6c7c0e000000"),
       "userId": ObjectId("5061f8c66096eee07d000008") 
    },
     {
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("505bf9476096ee990200000e"),
       "userId": ObjectId("505c2daea9d397f2260001ce") 
    },
      {
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("50422b75743d6c700e000004"),
       "userId": ObjectId("506cff736096ee1e26000384") 
    },
     {
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("50422b66743d6c6b0e000000"),
       "userId": ObjectId("505c2daea9d397f2260001cf") 
    },
     {
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("5050e86aa9d3977b67000000"),
       "userId": ObjectId("506494ef6096ee021f000064") 
    },
     {
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("50422b53743d6c7c0e000000"),
       "userId": ObjectId("504d72246096ee2348000008") 
    },
     {
       "userId": ObjectId("50735e8e6096ee7c510002b9"),
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("5046c73e6096ee1b77000001") 
    } 
  ]
}
```

Here's a second document:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("505c2da0a9d397f2260000b7"),
"contacts": [
      {
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("50422b66743d6c6b0e000000"),
       "userId": ObjectId("505c2da0a9d397f2260000b8") 
    },
     {
       "userId": ObjectId("5061f8c66096eee07d000008"),
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("50422b53743d6c7c0e000000") 
    },
     {
       "userId": ObjectId("50735e8e6096ee7c510002b9"),
       "userGroupId": ObjectId("5046c73e6096ee1b77000001") 
    } 
  ]
}
```

You'll notice that both documents have a userId of ObjectId("50735e8e6096ee7c510002b9") in them. I run this command:

```
db.collection.find({ 'contacts': 
    {$elemMatch: { userId: ObjectId("50735e8e6096ee7c510002b9") } }
});
```

Which should (I think) return both documents. But it only returns the second document. Not the first. I have also tried:

```
db.collection.find({'contacts.userId': ObjectId("50735e8e6096ee7c510002b9") });
```

which does the same thing as the $elemMatch query.

I'm probably missing something really elementary, but if you guys could offer some advice I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I just realized that contacts isn't an array, it's a numerically indexed object.. (assume conversion from a php array is responsible for that) - would this be the problem? Why is it returning anything then?

Comment: The fact that `contacts` is a numerically keyed object instead of an array is definitely the problem here.  These queries shouldn't be returning anything (and didn't when I tried them on these docs).

Comment: Correction - Rock Mongo is interpreting this incorrectly. I looked at the data from the console and it IS an array. Corrected the code above.

Comment: You're missing a `}` in your `$elemMatch` query, but other than that it's working as expected for me now, with both those queries returning both documents.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, my actual documents are much larger, so I simplified, this example is bad because it's working here, but not on my actual data. Maybe an index is corrupt or something. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I had the same problem - rock mongo showing my array as an object hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the application layer it turns out, not Mongo. One of the records was numerically keyed, the other was not, I just had been working with Rock Mongo which seems to key all the arrays.

Thanks for your help JohnnyHK